# web scraping - nested dict

Tags: python, dictionary, web-scraping, nested

I am looking for a way to transform nested dictionary to dataframe

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
r = requests.get('https://olxdata.azurewebsites.net/olx?city=wszystkie&dataType=mieszkania')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
print(soup)
```

As you could see the format is as below, a dictionary with list of dictionaries as a value:

```
{"olx":[{"date":"2020-04-30T00:00:00","toSell":27964,"toRent":41664}(...)], "otodom":[{"date":"2020-04-30T00:00:00","toSell":27964,"toRent":41664}(...)]
```

There are two elements in this dictionary - ideally I would like them to be an index like below:

|  | date | toSell | toRent |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| olx |  |  |  |
| otodom |  |  |  |

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

r = requests.get('https://olxdata.azurewebsites.net/olx?city=wszystkie&dataType=mieszkania')
df = pd.DataFrame()
for x in r.json():
    s_df = pd.DataFrame(r.json()[x])
    s_df['type_of'] = x
    df = pd.concat([df, s_df], axis=0)
print(df)
```

This would return:

```
date    toSell  toRent  type_of
0   2020-04-30T00:00:00 27964   41664   olx
1   2020-05-01T00:00:00 28071   41678   olx
2   2020-05-02T00:00:00 27884   41646   olx
3   2020-05-03T00:00:00 27724   41574   olx
4   2020-05-04T00:00:00 28021   42299   olx
... ... ... ... ...
842 2022-08-20T00:00:00 154562  12675   otodom
843 2022-08-21T00:00:00 154157  12753   otodom
844 2022-08-22T00:00:00 153991  12488   otodom
845 2022-08-23T00:00:00 154419  12699   otodom
846 2022-08-24T00:00:00 154728  12772   otodom
```